# Accessing a controller from inside a callback function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have the following AngularJS controller:

```
controllers.controller('QueuesCtrl', ['$scope', 'QueueRes',function($scope,QueueRes) {

    $scope.queues = QueueRes.query();
    this.queue={};

    this.create = function() {
        QueueRes.save(this.queue,function(){
            this.queue={};
        })

    };

  }]);
```

The object this.queue is a form, that I want to reset after I successfully POST the data.  The `this.queue={};` inside of the callback function doesn't work (which makes sense since `this` is different in that context).  If I move `this.queue={};` to outside of the callback, my code works, but resets the password regardless of the outcome of the POST operation, which is not what I desire.

How can I access the controller from inside the callback ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`this`** (controller object reference) is different from **$scope** (view model bound to html template).

If you want to reset `queue` on $scope, you can directly use

`$scope.queue = {};`

Otherwise, you can store `this` in a variable and use that variable to set queue.

```
controllers.controller('QueuesCtrl', ['$scope', 'QueueRes',function($scope,QueueRes) {
    var me = this;

    $scope.queues = QueueRes.query();
    me.queue={};
    this.create = function() {
        QueueRes.save(this.queue,function(){
            me.queue={};
        })
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: That's correct, I answered is as though the OP should use `this` in the callback, but they really need to change the `$scope`